# Determinants of differential equation matrices are complex

Tags: matrices, determinant, bessel-functions

I have generated various determinants for a system of differential equations, with the Bessel functions, which generate complex values for apparently all levels of n. I show here one of the determinants. What can I do to identify a level of n that yields real values?

For instance, one of the Bessel-function determinants is given by:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
    B_n=-\frac{1}{3} i^{-n} \left(2.25 \left(J_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)-J_{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right) Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+6 J_n\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) \left(\frac{3}{2} Y_{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\\n Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\right) (J_n(1) H_{n-1}^{(1)}(1)-J_{n-1}(1) H_n^{(1)}(1))
\end{array}
\end{equation}$

Here $J_{n}$ are $Y_{n}$  the Bessel function of n degree of the first and second kind respectively. I have quadruple-checked all matrices, and they seem to be fine.  So I don't know what to do about these matrices in order to find real-valued determinants.

What can I do to find the right levels of n that give real values?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: This question is quite unclear. What do you mean by “generated various determinants for a system of differential equations”? And isn't that expression for $B_n$ real-valued whenever $n$ is an even integer?

Comment: @HansLundmark No, it is certainly not. Here is one of the first values by levels of n. $3 i \left(J_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_0\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_0\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$

Comment: Oh, I see, there are complex-valued Hankel functions $H_\alpha^{(1)}$ in there too, not just the factor $i^{-n}$... But I still don't really understand what it is you want to do with those differential equations.

Comment: Yes, maybe un-thumb down the question? I wanted to find the levels of n that give real values.

Comment: The downvote came from somebody else. I'm just trying to understand what the point of all this is. What are those differential equations? How are the determinants related to them? Why do you want/expect things to be real? This looks a bit like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you ask about your attempted solution Y to problem X instead of asking about the actual problem X.

Comment: OK, sorry about that. I have computed the deteminants of matrices of differential equations. One of these determinants is copied above, and as the equations in the elements vary according to levels of $n$, I am solving each of these determinants for level n=1, 2, 3, .... If the values are complex or real affects the solutions.

Comment: I still don't know what matrices you are talking about, or what “equations in the elements” means. But never mind, I'm going to leave this question for others to worry about...

Comment: Lets just look at this one determinant. It makes things more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I get these determinant values for the first 20 levels of n:

$**\left\{3 i \left(J_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_0\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_0\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_1(1) H_0^{(1)}(1)-J_0(1) H_1^{(1)}(1)),3 \left(J_2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_2(1) H_1^{(1)}(1)-J_1(1) H_2^{(1)}(1)),-3 i \left(J_3\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_3\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_3(1) H_2^{(1)}(1)-J_2(1) H_3^{(1)}(1)),-3 \left(J_4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_3\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_3\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_4(1) H_3^{(1)}(1)-J_3(1) H_4^{(1)}(1)),3 i \left(J_5\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_5\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_5(1) H_4^{(1)}(1)-J_4(1) H_5^{(1)}(1)),3 \left(J_6\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_5\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_5\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_6\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_6(1) H_5^{(1)}(1)-J_5(1) H_6^{(1)}(1)),-3 i \left(J_7\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_6\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_6\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_7\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_7(1) H_6^{(1)}(1)-J_6(1) H_7^{(1)}(1)),-3 \left(J_8\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_7\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_7\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_8\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_8(1) H_7^{(1)}(1)-J_7(1) H_8^{(1)}(1)),3 i \left(J_9\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_8\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_8\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_9\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_9(1) H_8^{(1)}(1)-J_8(1) H_9^{(1)}(1)),3 \left(J_{10}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_9\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_9\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{10}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{10}(1) H_9^{(1)}(1)-J_9(1) H_{10}^{(1)}(1)),-3 i \left(J_{11}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{10}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{10}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{11}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{11}(1) H_{10}^{(1)}(1)-J_{10}(1) H_{11}^{(1)}(1)),-3 \left(J_{12}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{11}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{11}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{12}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{12}(1) H_{11}^{(1)}(1)-J_{11}(1) H_{12}^{(1)}(1)),3 i \left(J_{13}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{12}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{12}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{13}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{13}(1) H_{12}^{(1)}(1)-J_{12}(1) H_{13}^{(1)}(1)),3 \left(J_{14}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{13}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{13}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{14}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{14}(1) H_{13}^{(1)}(1)-J_{13}(1) H_{14}^{(1)}(1)),-3 i \left(J_{15}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{14}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{14}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{15}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{15}(1) H_{14}^{(1)}(1)-J_{14}(1) H_{15}^{(1)}(1)),-3 \left(J_{16}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{15}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{15}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{16}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{16}(1) H_{15}^{(1)}(1)-J_{15}(1) H_{16}^{(1)}(1)),3 i \left(J_{17}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{16}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{16}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{17}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{17}(1) H_{16}^{(1)}(1)-J_{16}(1) H_{17}^{(1)}(1)),3 \left(J_{18}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{17}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{17}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{18}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{18}(1) H_{17}^{(1)}(1)-J_{17}(1) H_{18}^{(1)}(1)),-3 i \left(J_{19}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{18}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{18}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{19}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{19}(1) H_{18}^{(1)}(1)-J_{18}(1) H_{19}^{(1)}(1)),-3 \left(J_{20}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{19}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-J_{19}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) Y_{20}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right) (J_{20}(1) H_{19}^{(1)}(1)-J_{19}(1) H_{20}^{(1)}(1))\right\}**$

Seemingly you have some real values there.

Comment: Thanks for this Sergio!

Comment: What code are you referring to? And how do you know that the values are real? The functions $H_\alpha^{(1)}$ are complex-valued.

Comment: Correct. My mistake.